# From SQL To MariaDB Key Constraint

Tags: mysql, mariadb

There is a table on sql like above and I try to run it on MariaDB,

```
 CREATE TABLE book (
      id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
      title VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
      author_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (id),
      KEY `fk_book _author_id` (`author_id `),
      CONSTRAINT `fk_book_author`FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES author (id)       
    ) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

MariaDb cannot run it on once.
The error is Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed.

So I change it to two scripts, first create a table and second add foreig key constraint and the run ok! But I have some questions

```
 CREATE TABLE book (
      id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      title VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
      author_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_book_author_id`
        FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES author (id)       
    ) ENGINE = InnoDB;

ALTER TABLE `book `  
   ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_book_author_id` FOREIGN KEY (`author_id`) REFERENCES `author` (`id`)
```

---

Τhe phrase key KEY `fk_book _author_id` (`_author_id`) ,which is used in first script , what it does.
It only defines the constraint? Could I use it on MariaDB script??
Can I run the first script to MariaDB at once?

Comment: ```KEY `fk_book _author_id` (`org_id`),``` - no such column in your table...

Comment: Show CREATE TABLE for **ALL** mentioned tables (i.e. for `author` table which you refer on in the FK definition). *The error is Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed.* Check the datatype of the `author.id` - it must be `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` and PK/UNIQUE.

Comment: Please share more details, like the full and exact error message and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

The code runs also to MariaBD and also to sql.

Akina said
The error is Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed. Check the datatype of the author.id - it must be SMALLINT UNSIGNED and PK/UNIQUE and so I check all of my data type e.tc. and the code runs also to MariaDB.